# How to change the variables of a factory with async call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am sort of new to Angularjs and I am trying to find the optimal structure to do such flow:

1. Get an access_token from my server asynchronously
2. Store it in a provider as a variable to be used in the future
3. Make async calls to the third party server with the access_token

My factory currently looks like this

```
app.factory('SomeFactory',['$resource', function($resource){
    //access_token only needs to be set once
    var access_token = 0; 
    var request = $resource('/my/server/').get();
    request.promise.then(function(result){
            access_token = result;
        }

    );
    return $resource('https://third.party/:token',{token: access_token});
}])
```

I can't set the access_token, the call back function is to be destroyed somehow.

Also how can I form a chain, so that third party cannot be called until the access_token has been set first?

Comment: Is it necessary to have it as a factory? I mean is it necessary to return the $resource from the factory?

Comment: Not necessarily, since I am new to angularjs coming from a backend dev, I simply want to avoid boilerplate codes. Is there a better design pattern that better suits my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
app.factory('SomeFactory',['$resource, $q', function($resource, $q){
    var service = {};

    //access_token only needs to be set once
    var access_token = null; 

    getAccessToken = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (access_token) {
            deferred.resolve(access_token);
        } else {
            $resource('/my/server/').then(function(result){
                access_token = result;
                deferred.resolve(access_token);
            });    
        }

        return deferred.promise;    
    }

    service.callThirdParty = function() {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        getAccessToken.then(function(access_token) {
            $resource('https://third.party/:token',{token: access_token}).then(function(result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            })
        })

        return deferred.promise;
    }


    return service;
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get an error at the second `deferred = $q.defer()`, I am guessing that it is deferred to early? The error message is something like `$q does not have function defer`